# How to use like clause in code iginiter query() WITH BIND PARAMS?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

How to use like clause in code iginiter query() WITH BIND PARAMS?

Eg:
When I use

```
$query = 'SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE %?';
$name = 'foo';
$db->this->query($query,array($name));
//the clause generated
//SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE id LIKE '%'foo'%' 
//I expected this
//SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE id LIKE '%foo'
```

I don't to put param values inside query and use like below:
$query = 'SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%foo';

Also I can not use $this->db->like() function as my query consists of:
INSERT IGNORE 
and 
INSERT INTO table SELECT col FROM table2;

Please suggests?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE ?';
$name = '%foo';
$this->db->query($query,array($name));
```

Comment: This is right answer but need to fix `$db->this->query` to `$this->db->query`

Comment: Thanks, I just copied it from author of the question. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

just **use CodeIgniter Query Builder**

```
$name = 'foo';

$query = $this
    ->db
    ->select('mycol')
    ->like('name', $name)
    ->get('mytable');
```

Answer (score 1):

codeigniter will replace `?` with `'params'` value. 
if you write this

```
 $query = 'SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE %?';
 $name = 'foo';
 //$db->this->query($query,array($name)); //you wrote this line wrong.
 //it should be like this
  $this->db->query($query,array($name));
```

it will produce

```
SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE %'foo' //inverse comma after % ,actually before and after foo.
```

So your right way will be

```
 $query = 'SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE ?';
 $name = '%foo';    
 $this->db->query($query,array($name));
```

It will produce

```
SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%foo'
```

**NOTE**
 You wrote this which is wrong

```
$db->this->query($query,array($name));
```

Right way

```
 $this->db->query($query,array($name));
```